# Variable won't assign in IE7, but assigns perfectly fine in IE8+ and any other browser

Tags: javascript, dom-events, internet-explorer-7

In this slightly lengthy code snippet:

```
(function() {
    var element = function(str) {
        return document.getElementById(str);
        },

        parent = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].getElementsByTagName('li'),
        len = parent.length,

        swap_slide = function(slide){
            return function(event) {
                event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
                
                var slides = element('main').getElementsByTagName('div'),
                    len = slides.length;
                for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
                    slides[i].style.display = 'none';
                }
                slide.style.display = 'block';
            }
        };

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        var link = parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0],
            slide = element(parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').substr(1));

        if (link.addEventListener) {
            link.addEventListener('click', swap_slide(slide), false);
        } else if (link.attachEvent) {
            link.attachEvent('onclick', swap_slide(slide));
        }
    }

    if (!element(location.hash.substr(1)))
        element('slajd-0').style.display = 'block';
    else 
        element(location.hash.substr(1)).style.display = 'block';
})();
```

everything works fine in Chrome, Opera, IE9, IE8, Safari, however in IE7 variable `slide` is `null`, IE7 reports the error in the function `swap_slide`, however the error might be somewhere else. I'm not sure if this is a scope error that I caused or is it simple IE retardation?

**EDIT**: The error IE spits out is:

> Error: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Comment: What is the error reported in swap_slide?

Comment: The error IE reports is: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined, BTW: I use IE9 and change the modes to IE7, but I don't think that could cause any problems

Comment: If slide is null, then it seems the problem would be starting when slide is assigned a value by the element() call. What is the DOM element it's supposed to be getting there (I just can't tell from looking at the code)?

Comment: Just a guess: In the second for loop try changing `.getAttribute('href')` to `.href`

Comment: @ZippyV that didn't work out, but thanks anyway.
@user `element(parent[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].getAttribute('href').substr(1));` if you mean this, this basically gets the href of the `<a>` element, strips the first character (which is #, since it only points to an ID) and uses that string in `element()` (which is an alias for `document.getElementById()`) to find the element by it's ID

Comment: Oh, I am wrong. It appears IE7 returns the whole URL, not just the contents of the href property, but to where it's end-destination will be. So it was http://url#hash, not simply #hash Thanks everyone for helping em resolve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
getAttribute('href')
```

to

```
getAttribute('href',2)
```

to get the href as defined and not as a expanded URL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx